# Recursive Upload to Azure-Files / Create Subfolder

Tags: c#, azure, azure-files

i want to Upload a folder recursivly to an azure-files storage.
The file structure usually has several subfolders.
What is the best way to create the subfolders in azure-files?

```
    foreach (string fullLocalFilename in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(locationOfFolderToUpload, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fullLocalFilename);
                FileInfo localfile = new FileInfo(fullLocalFilename);
                var root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
                string strPfad = localfile.DirectoryName.Substring(3);
                var folder = root.GetDirectoryReference(strPfad);
                Console.WriteLine(strPfad);
                folder.CreateIfNotExists();
                CloudFile file = folder.GetFileReference(localfile.Name);
                if (file.Exists() == false) {
                    file.Create(localfile.Length);
                    file.UploadFromFile(fullLocalFilename);
                    Console.WriteLine(fullLocalFilename);
                }
}
```

WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not found.

Comment: What is the line where the 404 happens?

Comment: @ folder.CreateIfNotExists(); when the file are more than one subfolder from the root-path. I do not know how to create a subfolder like root\abc\cba

Comment: The method you are using is the SDK which mimics API calls, not SMB classic operations. It means you cannot indicate full paths, GetRootDirectoryReference obtains 1 level reference only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make use of [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement), it supports uploading directory to azure as well create the same structure like in local path. Please install the latest version [1.0.0 of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/). Note that if you have installed other azure storage sdk, please uninstall them first.

For example, if I have a local folder like below:

[image]

Use the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File;

namespace AzureDataMovementTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string storageConnectionString = "xxxx";
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

            CloudFileClient fileClient = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference("t22");
            fileShare.CreateIfNotExists();

            CloudFileDirectory fileDirectory= fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();

            //here, I want to upload all the files and subfolders in the follow path.
            string source_path = @"F:\temp\1";

            //if I want to upload the folder 1, then use the following code to create a file directory in azure.
            CloudFileDirectory fileDirectory_2 = fileDirectory.GetDirectoryReference("1");
            fileDirectory_2.CreateIfNotExists();



            UploadDirectoryOptions directoryOptions = new UploadDirectoryOptions
            {
                Recursive = true
            };

            var task = TransferManager.UploadDirectoryAsync(source_path,fileDirectory_2,directoryOptions,null);
            task.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("the upload is completed");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

After the code completes running, nav to azure portal -> file storage:

[image]

Please let me know if you have more issues.